# command line option used in a module and in the main script

Tags: perl, perl-module, getopt-long

I have a module `misc` which is used by a few scripts. Each script accept two standard options (`-help` and `-verbose`) as well as a bunch of its own ones.

So, every scripts now has

```
my ($verbose,$quiet) = (1,0);
my $help = undef;
...
GetOptions("verbose|v+" => \$verbose, "quiet|q+" => \$quiet, "help|h" => \$help,
           ....)
  or die "GetOptions: error (see above)\n";
if (defined $help) { usage(); exit; }
$verbose -= $quiet;
```

which is already boring.

Now, I want the `misc` functions to be aware of the value of `$verbose` too, so I have to move `$verbose` et al to `misc` and use `$misc::verbose` in scripts:

misc:

```
our $verbose = 1;
my $quiet = 0;
our $help = undef;
our %common_options = ("verbose|v+" => \$verbose, "quiet|q+" => \$quiet, "help|h" => \$help);
sub set_verbose () { $verbose -= $quiet; }
```

script:

```
GetOptions(\%misc::common_options,"verbose|v","quiet|q","help|h",
           "count=i" => \$count, "start=i" => \$start, "mincoverage=i" => \$mincoverage,
           "output=s" => \$output, "input=s" => \$input, "targets=s" => \$targets)
  or die "GetOptions: error (see above)\n";
if (defined $misc::help) { usage(); exit; }
misc::set_verbose();
```

which does not look much better (and appears to not work anyway, at least `-help` is ignored).

So, what do people use for command line options shared between modules and scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I do it simpler:

- use a hash to store command line options

  ```
    GetOptions(\%args, "xxx1","xxx2");
  ```
- Pass that hash - as is - to ANY classes' constructrs, or module setters

  ```
    my $object = Class1->new(%args, %constructor_args);
    Module2::set_args(\%args); #
  ```
- Argument setter in the module would be:

  ```
    # Module2
    our %args;
    sub set_args { %args = %{ shift }; }
  ```

This ensures that:

- I NEVER have to worry about moving parameters from scope to scope and having to modify some calls. They are ALL passed around 100% of needed places
- Neat and non-messy code. Since we are broadcasting, we don't need to worry about subscribers' individual needs.
- Pattern easily replicated to ALL classes you own.

As a matter of fact, if you want to be extra crafty, you can even replace `Module2::set_args(\%args);` calls for several classes with a smart code that:

1. Reads in a list of loaded modules
2. Checks which of those modules implements `set_args()` call via `UNIVERSAL::can()`
3. Calls the supporting modules'  `set_args()` call

The latter makes the code even cleaner, in that N calls to `set_args()` one for each non-class module is are all replaced by one `set_all_modules_args()` call.

Comment: thanks, but this is way over my head. First, I do not use classes (unless provided by system modules), i.e., there are no classes in my `misc`. Second, your solution seems to be geared towards "many modules, one main program", as opposed to my situation of "many programs, one main module".

Comment: @sds - (1) simply ignore the class pieces then and use module pieces. I renamed Class2 to Module2 to be more intuiyive in my examples. (2) Each of your many scripts will have `GetOptions(\%args, "xxx1","xxx2");   Module2::set_args(\%args);`

Answer (score 0):

Have a module that's responsible for getting standard options.

Use this module, and everyone will be able to access the verbose() call.

```
package StandardOptions;


use base qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(verbose);

use Getopt::Long;

Getopt::Long::Configure(qw(pass_through));


my $helpNeeded;
my $verbose
GetOptions ("help" => \$helpNeeded, "verbose" => $verbose);


if ($helpNeeded) {
    #provide help
    exit(0);
}

sub verbose {
   return $verbose;
}

1;
```